# Why should it int value comes for floating value?

Tags: c

```
 void main()
{
char a;
float f = 10;
for(a=1; a<=5; a++)
{
    f-=.2;
    printf("\nf = %g", f);
}
}
```

Here the for loop is executive five times and each time the value of f is decremented by .2.But according to me the final value of f should be 9.0 but output is 9.
Why the value of f is not coming in decimal point ?

Comment: What language is this? C?

Comment: yes sir C language.

Comment: A better question would be "why should it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal point is not shown for `%g` conversions if there is no non-zero digit following the decimal point. You can use `%f` instead, or explicitly specify the number of digits you want to see behind the decimal point, for example `%.1g` to always show 1 digit.

Comment: @G Sliepen Sir can you add reason The decimal point is not shown for %g conversions ?

Comment: That's the way it is. The reason is probably concision of the print, after all 9 says as much as 9.0000, isn't it?

Comment: @Ron Because that's what `%g` is for. It's there only to remove the trailing zeroes, otherwise it does the same thing as `%f` or `%e` (both of which are much more common). Why did you use the quite uncommon `%g` instead of `%f` which almost everyone uses?

Comment: @Ron Just because `%g` specifies the shortest representation of `%e` or `%f`, accordingly to this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

Because your final value of `f` is `9` without a decimal part. So that, `printf` just doesn't print it.
If you need to print the decimal part in such case, you can use `%.1f` in your `printf`, like this:
`printf( "\nf = %.1f", f )`